# Obtener valor de una variable dentro de un setState en otra clase Flutter - Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Tengo una clase principal donde agrego otras clases para mostrarlas en la pantalla, por ejemplo, tengo un listado de objetos y entre todos ellos agrego un DropDownButton() que tengo en una clase a parte y que funciona correctamente, al cambiar el item seleccionado cambia su valor en el DropDown a través del setState y puedo hacer print() de ese valor dentro de la clase del DropDownButton, pero no puedo obtener el valor del item seleccionado desde la clase principal o en realidad no sé cómo hacerlo.

Así estructuro el DropDownButton dentro de la clase principal:

```
  List<String> list1 = [
    'Trabajo en altura',
    'Trabajos en caliente',
    'Trabajos eléctricos',
    'Excavaciones',
    'Trabajos con fluidos peligrosos',
    'Trabajos de izaje',
    'Trabajos en espacios confinados',
  ];

  List<String> list2 = [
    'Día 1',
    'Día 2',
    'Día 3',
    'Día 4',
    'Día 5',
    'Día 6',
    'Día 7',
  ];

    List<Widget> add_dropdown = List.generate(
        _count,
            (int i) =>
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8, // 20%
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: DropdownMenu(
                        itemsList: list1, dropdownVal: 'Trabajo en altura'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2, // 20%
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                    child: DropdownMenu(itemsList: list2, dropdownVal: "Día 1"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ));
```

Y así lo muestro:

```
Container(
                    height: heightList,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 10.0,
                    ),
                    child: ListView(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: add_dropdown,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Esta es la clase a parte donde tengo el DropDownButton():

```
class DropdownMenu extends StatefulWidget {

  final String dropdownVal;
  final List<String> itemsList;

  DropdownMenu({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemsList,
    @required this.dropdownVal,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _DropdownMenu();
  }

}

class _DropdownMenu extends State<DropdownMenu> {

  String dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(dropdownValue == null){
      dropdownValue = widget.itemsList.first;
    }

    //print(dropdownValue);

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFff0000)),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Color(0xFFff0000)
      ),
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
          //print(dropdownValue);
        });
      },
      items: widget.itemsList
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            //print(value);
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: AutoSizeText(
            value,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                color: Color(0xFFff0000),
            ),
            maxLines: 3,
            maxFontSize: 15.0,
            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            minFontSize: 2.0,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

La idea es poder obtener el valor que obtengo dentro del setState de DropDownMenu pero en la clase principal o la clase donde llamo a la clase DropDownMenu:

```
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
      //print(dropdownValue);
    });
```

Necesito pasarlo a la clase principal porque desde ahí guardaré todos los datos en la db de Firebase.

Espero puedan ayudarme,
desde ya,
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay librerias para manejar estado. Por ejemplo [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). Pero si no quieres usar librerias haz esto.

Pasa una función llamemosla `callback` al hijo `DropdownMenu`.

```
class DropdownMenu {
  ...
  Function callback;
  DropdownMenu({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemsList,
    @required this.dropdownVal,
    @required this.callback,
  });
...
```

En el mismo widget sólo llama `callback` en `onChanged`.

```
onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
      callback(newValue);
    });
```

En el padre. Pasa la función de tu logica de firebase ó haz `setState` y modifica lo que necesites.

```
void callback(String value) {
    // aqui accedes al valor del hijo
}
...
child: DropdownMenu(
    itemsList: list1, dropdownVal: 'Trabajo en altura', callback: callback),
```

Es una forma rápida de hacerlo pero poco recomendable ya que el código no escala de buena manera. Para eso usa bloc, provider u otras librerias.